# Approximation of wave impedance equation...

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, approximation

Wave impedance is give by the equation:

$$\eta = \sqrt{\frac{i~\omega \mu}{\sigma + i~\omega \varepsilon}}$$

where:

$$i = \sqrt{-1}$$

Now I want to make an approximation of this equation when $\sigma$ is much larger than $\omega\varepsilon$, that is:

$$\sigma >> \omega \varepsilon$$

The book says this should give:

$$\eta \approx \sqrt{\frac{\omega \mu}{\sigma}} \angle 45^\circ$$

I was just curious, how they came to this conclusion...

I could imagine that since $\sigma$ is much larger...it dominates in the denominator... so we can ignore the "$+ i~\omega \varepsilon$" term, yeilding:

$$\eta \approx \sqrt{\frac{i~\omega \mu}{\sigma}}$$

but there's still the "i" term to deal with...

unless i were to multiple the top and bottom by the complex conjugate, to yield:

$$\eta = \sqrt{\frac{i~\omega\mu(\sigma-i~\omega\varepsilon)}{\sigma^2 + i~(\omega\varepsilon)^2}}$$

$$\eta \approx \sqrt{\frac{i~\omega\mu\sigma}{\sigma^2}}$$

its just the same thing again...

Answer (score 2):

Start from $\sqrt{\frac{\mathrm{i} \omega \mu}{\sigma}} = \sqrt{\frac{\omega \mu}{\sigma}} \sqrt{\mathrm{i}}$.  $\sqrt{\mathrm{i}}$ is either $\angle 45^\circ$ or $\angle {-135^\circ}$.  Since $\sigma + \mathrm{i} \omega \varepsilon$ has a small positive argument, and $\mathrm{i} \omega \mu$ has argument $\angle 90^\circ$, we know we should retain the positive argument.

Comment: thanks.  by euler's $i = \cos(\pi/2) + i~\sin(\pi/2)= e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$, then: $\sqrt{i} = (e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}} )^{1/2} = e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}} = \angle 45^{\circ}$

Comment: @pico : Yes.  That is one square root.  There is another since $(\mathrm{e}^{-3\mathrm{i}\pi/4})^2 = \mathrm{i}$.  We have to use some other fact to decide which one to retain.